# 500エラーで画像、cssが表示されない

Tags: php

httpのテスト環境では正常に表示されていた画像やcssが、https環境で一部表示されず、500エラーが返ってきてしまいます。
確認するポイントがあれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

ブラウザで確認したところ、下記エラーになっているのはわかるのですが
混在コンテンツをどうやって特定させたらいいでしょうか。
ひたすらデバックをしていくしかないですか

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Security/%E6%B7%B7%E5%9C%A8%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%84

Comment: 混在コンテンツ云々については[ブラウザのコンソールに問題のURLが表示されている](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Security/%E6%B7%B7%E5%9C%A8%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%84#Web_%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E5%86%85%E3%81%AE%E8%AD%A6%E5%91%8A)ほか、HTMLのソースを表示して `http://` という文字列を検索するのも手です。ただ、500エラーはサーバー側でのエラーを示すものなので、混在コンテンツとは別の問題だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

コメントでも書いてくださっていましたが
複数の問題が同時に起こってきている可能性が高い気がしました。
もしそうであれば問題の切り分けからする必要がありますね。

500エラーは原因が様々あるようです。
http://bibabosi-rizumu.com/http500-internalservererror/

混在コンテンツの特定（http~という以前のパスをサイト内のソースから特定するという認識）は
ドリームウィーバーやatom、sublime等を使用していればディレクトリ内すべてのファイルから
検索置換ができると思います。
例）atomでしたらopenfolder→ctrl+shift+fでフォルダ内すべてのファイルの中から検索置換

linuxコマンドでしたら下記でいけると思います。
http://qiita.com/kkyouhei/items/b4ff839a2f36ba194df3

見当違いでしたらすみません、
・具体的にどんな作業をされたか
・具体的なエラーメッセージ
・どのような環境で作業されているか
などを追記していただけると
他の回答がつくかもしれません。

Comment: コメント、回答いただきありがとうございます